# Updating a label that shows a player in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

For a project i need to make a nim game and there must be a label that shows which players it is. But now i need to update a label after a player clicks on a button to take 1 or 2 coins. There must be 2 players and now i don't know how to do that.

Here's my script:

```
from tkinter import *

player = 1

def player_status():
    global player

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')

frame = Frame(root)

state = Label(frame, text="State: " + str(coins))
state.pack()
player = Label(frame, text="Player " + str(player) + " turns!")
player.pack()

takeonecoin = Button(frame, text="1 coin", commad=one_coin)
takeonecoin.pack()
taketwocoins = Button(frame, text="2 coins", command=two_coins)
taketwocoins.pack()

frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You code looks very messy, I would refer you to learn about OOP, objects and classes are almost necessary in creating games, even simple ones.

Comment: Start by defining a `Player` class and creating two instances of it. Then assign one of them to be the `current_player` and modify the rest of your functions to refer to that (as an argument or global variable). This will allow you to switch players simply by assigning a different value to `current_player`.

Comment: Bro, I checked your code, it isn't even working!

Comment: @martineau where in the code should i begin?

Comment: I've seen almost this exact code posted from at least two accounts, maybe more. The old questions seem to have been deleted, but I've seen this code on at least three different questions.

Comment: @BryanOakley This is the first time that i put my code on this site. I dont know where you talking about.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use "bind" option:
xxx.bind(, command that should execute)

For example:

```
takeonecoin = Button(frame, text="1 coin")
takeonecoin.bind('<Button-1>', one_coin)
takeonecoin.pack()
taketwocoins = Button(frame, text="2 coins")
taketwocoins.bind('<Button-1>', two_coin)
taketwocoins.pack()
```

It's my first answer, sorry for my English

Comment: when im doing this than i get this error = TypeError: one_coin() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @FreddieBo you need to define functions like def one_coin(event):

Comment: You shouldn't use `bind` on buttons. Instead, use the `command` attribute.